# dotenv exports undefined data

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I'm trying to export data from dotenv file, but does not work, I already installed dotenv but still not working

dotenv file:

```properties
PORT=3000
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://userfg:<password>@cluster0.45m0c4f.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
MONGO_DBNAME=inventario
```

JS file:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
module.exports.Config = {
  port: process.env.PORT,
  mongoURI: process.env.MONGO_URI,
  mongodbname: process.env.MONGO_DBNAME
};

console.log(process.env.PORT);
```

I get undefined when I call `process.env.PORT`, `process.env.MONGO_URI` and `process.env.MONGO_DBNAME`

[image: File structure]

Comment: is your config file imported to your main server.js or app.js file ?  also i would put ``require('dotenv').config();`` inside the main server file

Comment: yea I have installed dotenv  but got the same undefined

Comment: Is named .env and hosted in root directory, thanks

Comment: Which file is the JS file in your question?

Comment: Solved, thank you

Comment: This is not reproducible. I took all the code you've shown and it runs just fine with `Config` populated correctly

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Avoid whenever possible to call `require('dotenv').config();` directly.

Those variables are meant to be recovered as regular environment variables, in a transparent way.

The script trying to load the env-file is probably trying it too late, process.env might be already populated when `require('dotenv').config();` is called.

Try to either perform the `require('dotenv').config();` in the entry point (i.e. the index.js) or, my preferred approach, as a dynamic require in the node command line:

```bash
node -r dotenv/config index.js
```

Then remove the `require('dotenv').config();` altogether.

This approach is even documented in the [dotenv project](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#preload).

Take a look at [this sample project](https://github.com/sombriks/simple-knex-koa-example/blob/main/package.json#L9) if unsure about it.

Comment: _"This approach is even documented in the dotenv project"_... so is the way OP is using it. In fact, what OP has is the recommended / default usage

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*The script trying to load the envfile is trying it too late*". Surely `require('dotenv').config();` is called in the OPs code before the `process.env` properties are accessed?

Comment: @Phil no this is not, ENV files makes sense only on development stage, on production environments, containers and so on it should be transparent how the application gets those variables

Comment: @Bergii saw this problem before and this is why i recommend dynamic require.

Comment: `dotenv` won't override existing environment variables so it's safe to use in production code. I do agree with you on removing that sort of thing from code (I actually like [env-cmd](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd) better) but I just can't see how this answers the question

Comment: @Phil i never said it overrides, but i am do saying that `require('dotenv').config()` does. It answers the OP question because what i suggested works, the sample code i provided in the link works, i don't see any reason for downvotes, but it OP got things sorted out already i am ok with whatever other people think.

Comment: I didn't downvote but `require('dotenv').config()` most certainly does not override existing environment variables unless explicitly told to. See https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#override

Comment: @Phil no it doesn't, it wasn't the issue faced by the OP neither was i affirming it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce OP's problem so I'd say it's not about _when_ dotenv goes to work. I agree with @Bergi, this isn't specifically the problem